# How can I set up Admin role in CanCan?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

I want to add admin role to this. Admin should be able to destroy, and update everything.
Admin is `user.id = 1`

How can I code it in this?

**models/ability.rb**

```
if user
    .....
    can :read, :all 
    can [:create, :destroy], Comment, {:user_id => user.id}
    can [:destroy], Comment, {:commentable_id => user.id, :commentable_type => user.class.name}
    can [:create, :update], Community, {:user_id => user.id}
    .....
else
    can :read, :all 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You are so close it's not even funny.

You are looking for `can :manage, :all`

```
if user
  if user.admin? # or user.id == 1
    can :manage, :all
  else
    .....
    can :read, :all 
    can [:create, :destroy], Comment, {:user_id => user.id}
    can [:destroy], Comment, {:commentable_id => user.id, :commentable_type => user.class.name}
    can [:create, :update], Community, {:user_id => user.id}
    .....
  else
    can :read, :all 
end
```